# Best zombie weapon

Tags: science-based

In the event of a zombie apocalypse what would be the best cold arm to face the living dead?

Comment: I've not come across the term "cold arm" before. Presumably you mean "not a firearm", but there are lots of energetic weapons that don't need fire. It also depends massively on how your living dead actually function (magic or otherwise). You're more likely to get good answers if you clarify things a little.

Comment: @StarfishPrime I think he took the term "cold ammunition" and applied it to any weapon that could be (relatively) silent.

Comment: How do the undead function? Are the weapons custom-made, or historic weapons, or just improvised? Also, different situations require different types of weapons, you can't clear a small apartment with pole weapons, like a halberd, even though they're excellent for keeping zombies away on an open-field.

Comment: Welcome to the Worldbuilding Stack Exchange! Currently your post is a little shor and in danger of being closed. Please add more detail to your question and describe the situation your question is in a little more.

Comment: There are so many different weapons currently in use, from several kinds of knifes to atomic weapons. If there was a best weapon, there would only be one kind. Weapons are highly circumstantial. A zombie is just a worse version of a human, so it would be sufficient to use anything that would work against a human. I fail to see why a zombie would need a special approach. Please be aware that zombies are a metaphor for a large group of people threatening society like communists, terrorists and so on. The choice of weapon should really depend on your metaphor and not on it being the best

Comment: I'm sure there's already a question here somewhere about ideal weapons for a zombie apocalypse. I remember because someone answered with Tombstone from *BattleBots*. I'll link it if I can find it.

Comment: any weapons, walking dead zombies, and the term cold arm refers to melee weapons

Comment: Since zombies are stupid, slow and can't fight with any weapon, good old cold weapons are the best choice. A bunch of strong men armed with swords, spears, axes, and other weapons.

Comment: Mythbusters tested: It's an axe.

Answer (score 1):

That all depends on the powers, limitations, vulnerabilities, and other qualities of the "zombies" in a zombie apocalypse.

One suggestion would be a giant version of a walk behind push Reel lawnmower, an old type lawnmower like some of the older members may have sometimes used.

https://www.homedepot.com/p/EcoReel-18-in-Manual-Walk-Behind-Push-Reel-Mower-ER-18/206438446[1](https://www.homedepot.com/p/EcoReel-18-in-Manual-Walk-Behind-Push-Reel-Mower-ER-18/206438446)

I have often thought that a hypthetical giant version of a reel lawn mower, pushed by elephants perhaps, would be a good way to mow a path through an enemy phalanx of spearmen, a path that swordsmen could exploit to attack the phalanx from inside the gap created.

Here is a link to a picture of a combine harvester:

https://www.kubota.co.in/products/harvester/index.html[2](https://www.kubota.co.in/products/harvester/index.html)

If the blades of production combine harvesters are strong enough to cut through zombie bones and muscle as easily as through crops, a line of such combine harvesters side by side could mow down a zombie horde.  Of course the drivers' position would have to have sufficient defenses against any type of attack the zombies might be able to make.

This article:

https://www.agriland.ie/farming-news/fully-driverless-combine-harvester-by-2024/[3](https://www.agriland.ie/farming-news/fully-driverless-combine-harvester-by-2024/)

Claims that automated driver less combine harvesters may be commercially available by 2024.  If they do become available, and if their blades are strong enough to slice up zombies as easily as crops, they can be used against a horde of zombies without risking the lives of drivers.

If combine harvesters don't have the power to slice up zombies, survivors may have to invent versions of combine harvesters that have more power and can hack zombies to pieces.

There are riding brush mowers that can cut down thick overgrowth.  In some cases they are capable of cutting woody plant stems with about the same thickness as human bone.  Thus I can imagine a line of harvester combines mowing down a zombie horde, slicing the zombies into large pieces, and being followed by a line of riding bush mowers to slice up the large zombie pieces into tiny zombie pieces to make certain there aren't any pieces left capable of doing anything.

Of course it is possible that the zombie apocalypse will cause civilization to fall and gasoline supplies to be used up without any new production of gasoline.  Thus using harvester combines against hordes of zombies may no longer be possible while there are still hordes of zombies to fight off.

Thus the survivors may have to invent giant versions of the walk behind push reel mower to use against zombie hordes. Such giant zombie mowers would probably work best if pulled from ahead, except that the zombies might attack the animals and humans pulling them, so pushing from behind would seem to be safer.

You have have seen the movie *The Day of the Triffids* (1962) where two simultaneous disasters threaten human survival.  The vast majority of humans go blind, and triffids appear, meat-eating walking plants that prey on humans, most of which are now helpless and blind.

In the original novel *The Day of the Triffids* (1951) by John Wyndham the two disasters were not simultaneous.  The narrator was a child when he was one of the first people attacked by the triffids when they first appeared, and one of the few to survive. When the narrator grew up he became a professional triffid hunter, exterminating triffids wherever they showed up, and triffids were only a minor problem.

It isn't until the vast majority of humans go blind that triffids get out of hand and become a major menace.

As I remember, triffid hunters used "triffid guns" to slay triffids, devices that shot out rapidly spinning circular blades that could cut the stems of triffids.

So I can picture inventive humans during a zombie apocalypse inventing zombie guns - or possibly zombie crossbows - that shoot out rabidly spinning blades that slice through zombie bodies and cut them in half.

Such zombie guns might be used against lone zombies, or if they could loaded and fired fast enough, against a zombie horde.

If gunpowder is not available, spears might be the best weapons against a zombie horde, if the spearmen are trained to fight in a phalanx like formation.  Possibly a small minority of the warriors might be highly trained swordsmen or axemen who would attack the Zombie horde from the sides and/or rear while the spearmen were holding off the zombies in front.

If the spearmen cannot hold off the zombies & perhaps kill some of them, but are all killed or zombiefied, any victory by the swordmen attacking the zombies from behind would be Pyrrhic.

(addeed 10-25-19.  An ancient Dacian two handed *Falx* might be a good type of hand weapon to use against zombies, since it might be able to slice off heads, arms, and legs.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falx[4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falx))

And those are a few ideas about anti zombie weapons.

Comment: Cold arm refers to melee weapons and we are thinking realistic zombies such as the ones in the walking dead

Comment: @Caleb  Fighting in a melee is a very bad idea.  It is much better to have a battle formation when fighting an enemy horde, and it is possible that even zombies might prefer to fight in a formation.  If Zombies have the strength and body structure of humans, making a mower strong enough to cut through their flesh and bone might be difficult.  But on the other hand if zombies can't jump any higher or farther than normal humans, building mowers too wide and/or too tall for zombies to leap over should be easy.  A good hand weapon to slice up zombies might be a ancient Dacian Falx.

Comment: We are not talking hoards

Comment: Zombies cannot think

Answer (score 1):

We need more information.

I'll assume cold arm means not a firearm.

While it does depend a bit on the type of zombie you are facing, and the particular scenario.

For example a doomsday prepper in the US would have more access to weapons than a suburban mom in the UK.

And I'm Legend zombies are different from the typical zombies who are in turn are different from certain zombies that seem to be able to think, which I personally don't think they are zombies.

And again the context of a single survivor is different from a town militia to a military unit.

So again we need more information. 
But general points include.

- First fire arms would still be the most effective overall weapons.
  Even for close quarters we have SMG and pistols. So if you want to have people using melee weapons in better be explained in a logical manner.
- Cut and thrust swords with hand protection and reach are an obvious choice. 
  Sabres or rapiers or backswords are favorite. 
  They have the speed you need to quickly dispatch zombies, they have the reach to be able to kill them from afar, to both minimize risk of infection and biting, and they are very deadly with any part while offering hand protection. 
  So for a single use side arm or silent zombie killer or lone melee character they are the best choice.
  I almost forgot. Swords can be easily worn on the side like they did in history.
  A poleweapon can't be worn.
- In more organized formations you might be thinking of spears. 
  That is short 1-2 meters spears. 
  They thing about spears is they have more reach and leverage. 
  Allowing you to wound the opponent before they can reach you.
  Of course they are the dominant historical weapon but for personal usage the sword was more popular. 
  However organized formations would give spears a greater advantage over swords. 
  So a shield wall, yes that one, would offer many spear points working to constantly thrust and cut and disable any zombie that gets too close. 
  With numbers you have the benefit of more spear points meaning more coverage.
- For cavalry spears or lances or whatever pointy things one a stick are
  an obvious choice. If for whatever reason people in your world are going around on horseback or bikes attacking zombies with anythingm then spears/lances are the logical choice.
- Blunt force trauma weapons deliver more powerful hits and are great against armor. But for rotting flesh you want a quick stabby thing that can penetrate the neck real fast. Trying to smash the head of a zombie is a wasted effort if you can just give it a quick a stab and it dies.
- Axes are good weapons. They have a bit more punch and for cutting you don't have to worry about edge alignment. But swords are easier to wear and best of all can thrust which is far deadlier. Again if a thrust kills then you just thrust it instead of trying to lob heads off and make a big mess.
- However if you zombies do require complete head cutting then we are back to something like falchions or Dane axes.
- The two weapons above have reach and more leverage than say an arming sword. 
  So trying to chop and entire head off with one blow is much easier than with a sword or a mace. Maces in general I don't see being useful. The skull is big and tough, and even that of a zombie should take a lot more than one blow to damage.
  But a big axe or a falchion would offer than quick and agile movements while still delivering devastating blows.
  Certain type of curved sword could be useful as well.

And lastly. Firearms would still be the best weapon.

Comment: Cold arm actually refers to melee weapons and guns would not be the most effective because you have to account for the ammo and the noise and blades require the know how to use them and maintenance so ultimately I would choose a blunt above a blade but personally I would have a spear and a bat as my primaries

Comment: Actually melee weapons need more maintenance than guns you know. 
That's why armies had extra supplies and blacksmiths...etc even on campaign. 
You also don't find many saber blades or spear heads lying around.
But you can find automatic rifles and pistols. 
Ammo is only a concern in certain places. 
The military, paramilitary, and police would have them. 
You are not fencing. You don't have to think about foot work or your opponents blade, you just slash and thrust,

Comment: You do have to worry about cutting yourself, blunt weapons do not require maintenance, ammo is a concern as I said zombie "apocalypse"